# JavaScript not working in page

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to call an alert function on the click of a button, but it's not firing.

```
<button aria-hidden="false" type="button" title="Test" onclick='alert("hii");'>
    <div>×</div></button>
```

Here, this page I am rendering it as a body (with jQuery bundles) in another page (layout page) whose head section also contains jQuery files. Below is the sample code.

Layout.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css") 
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js"></script>

    </head>)

    <body>
    @RenderBody()
    </body>

</html>
```

Template.cshtml:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Scripts")
<button aria-hidden="false" type="button" title="Test" 
onclick='alert("hii");'><div>×</div></button>
```

This Template.cshtml code will be render in the body section of the layout.cshtml.

Comment: Have you verified that the `onclick` property is present in the rendered html? Do you get visual feedback that the button is being pressed, or might there be some element overlapping it? If you manually run `$('button[title="Test"]').click()`, do you trigger the alert?

Comment: Yes its present there

Comment: Do you get visual feedback that the button is being pressed, or might there be some element overlapping it? If you manually run `$('button[title="Test"]').click()`, do you trigger the alert?

Comment: Actually its not at all triggering while pressing the button and running manually as u mentioned.         The rendered html is like  as below   
      <html>
      <head>
      //here is one Jquery library
      </head>
      <body>
      <iframe>
      <html>
      <head>
      // Here is another Jquery Library
      </head>
     <body>
     //here simple alert is getting triggered.

      @RenderBody()//Here my cshtml get renders with another Jquery 
       library,In this body i have a button which is not working


        </body>
      </iframe>
      </body>

Answer (score 0):

You Can check if your page not having same JS reference multiple times. As you have added scripts in head section as well as you have script bundle in template.cshtml page that can make issue.

Comment: What issue could that cause, that could prevent a click listener defined in markup from showing an alert?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to update your **layout.cshtml** like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>

@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")

</head>

<body>
@RenderBody()
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

This way your page will render fully before your scripting goes to work.
Note: Its always a good practice to put your `@RenderBody()` section inside `div`